# How do you get version of Platform in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a page where I display all sorts of info and I would like to display either the android Sdk used or the iOS version used

How can I retrieve those in xamarin forms? Looked at xamarin essentials but cannot find it.

Result wanted

Android Sdk
29 (10)

ioS
14

Hope makes sense

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get via Dependency Service. Create Interface in shared project and then implement this interface in platform specific projects.

**Shared Project**

```
public interface IDeviceInfo
    {
        string GetOSVersion();
    }
```

**iOS Project**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(DeviceInfo_iOS))]
namespace App1.iOS
{
    public class DeviceInfo_iOS : IDeviceInfo
    {
        public string GetOSVersion()
        {
            return UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion;
        }
    }
}
```

**Android Project**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(DeviceInfo_Android))]
namespace App1.Droid
{
    public class DeviceInfo_Android : IDeviceInfo
    {
        public string GetOSVersion()
        {
            return "Android Sdk " + (int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt +" (" + Build.VERSION.Release +")";
        }
    }
}
```

Call the DependencyService in Shared Project

```
var version = DependencyService.Get<IDeviceInfo>().GetOSVersion();
```

Comment: hi one thing it seems that Build.VERSION.Sdk is obsolete but there is no replacement that I can easily see.

Comment: We can use (int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt. I have edited the answer.